# Regex: match and tokenize in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to extract certain patterns from the input string. These patterns are `+, - , *, / , (, ),` `log` , `integer`  and `float numbers`.

Here's example for the needed behavior:

```
//input string
var str = "log6*(12+5)/2-34.2"

//wanted result
var rightResp = Array("log","6","*","(","12","+","5",")","/","2","-","34.2")
```

I have tried to do this for some time but I have to admit that regex is not my specialty.  Next piece of code shows where I am stuck:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

var str = "log6*(12+5)/2-34.2"

val pattern = new Regex("(\\+|-|log|\\*|\\/|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)")

pattern.findAllIn(str).toArray
```

Result is not good cause there is no matching for brackets "`(`" and "`)`"  and also numbers , both `integer(6,12,5,2)` and `float(34.2)` are messed up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try [`[+()*/-]|log|[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/bT7uA7/1).

Comment: @stribizhev thanks a lot !  If you post it as an answer I will gladly upvote and accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
[+()*/-]|log|[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT7uA7/1)

The regex contains 3 alternatives joined with the help of `|` alternation operator.

- `[+()*/-]` - matches a single literal character: `+`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `/`, `-` (note that the hyphen is not escaped as it is at the end of the character class)
- `log` - a literal letter sequence `log`
- `[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+` - a float number that accepts values like `.05`, `5.55` as it matches...

  - `[0-9]*` - 0 or more digits
  - `\\.?` - and optional (1 or 0) literal periods
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digitis.

Here is a [Scala code sample](http://ideone.com/0aw37k):

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
object Main extends App {
   var str = "log6*(12+5)/2-34.2"
   val pattern = new Regex("[+()*/-]|log|[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+")
   val res = pattern.findAllIn(str).toArray
    println(res.deep.mkString(", "))
}
```

Result: `log, 6, *, (, 12, +, 5, ), /, 2, -, 34.2`

Comment: If you need to add more single character support, add that to the character class (only `[` and `]` will have to be escaped there). If you need to support more sequences, add them with `|` alternation operator.

Comment: Will this work as the OP expects if `str` is instead `"log6*(-12+5)/2-34.2"`?

Comment: @grubjesic: Is that in scope of your question?